# Can Sass recognise a size and apply a condition?

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, frontend

I'm trying to realise a simple container in Sass. The container has 60px min-height and 80px height, with inside a simple paragraph.

Now, anytime I add a new paragraph in the container, the height increase, depending on how many paragraphs I insert in the container.

What I'm would like to know, it's if there is any way to set a condition that if the container exceeded 100px height, the border would change the colour.

Thank you guys!

Comment: No you can't. Use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 0):

Note: When using SASS there are two distinct periods to keep in mind for values: values computed at compile time, ie when transpiling to CSS, and at render time, ie when the transpiled CSS is applied by the browser. The container's computed height value is something that can *only* be known at render time.

The closest CSS comes to having conditionals is its selectors. SASS has rich conditional selectors, but, like CSS, they cannot (and likely will never) be able to select elements based on render-time dimension values.

When you think about it, this makes sense. For example if you could select elements based on height being greater or less than a fixed value, you could have one selector for elements with height > 100px that sets the height to 90px, and one selector for elements with height < 100px that sets the height to 110px, leading to a never ending logic loop.

In your specific case you might be able to use selectors such as `:nth-child` to achieve a result close to what you're asking for. If you know that with two paragraphs the container will always have a height less than 100px, but with 3 paragraphs the container will always have a height greater than 100px, you can target the 3rd paragraph, perhaps using its `::before` or `::after` element to create your border.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}
div > p:nth-child(3)::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h5>Two paragraphs will have no border</h5>
<div>
    <p>haha</p>
    <p>hoho</p>
</div>
<br/>
<h5>Three or more paragraphs will have a border</h5>
<div>
    <p>haha</p>
    <p>hoho</p>
    <p>haha</p>
    <p>hoho</p>
</div>
```

This is probably as close as you're going to get to height based conditionals in SASS/CSS. Of course, if your paragraphs have variable heights, this solution may not work.

Comment: He's asking about Sass, though, not pure CSS.